# Issue in accessing Microsoft Access file from Python using pyodbc module

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am unable to access a Microsoft Access file (.accdb) from Python using the pyodbc module. Below is the patch of code I am using. I have checked my version of Python as well as the Access DB, both are 64-bit.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ='+'{};Uid={};Pwd={};'.format(db_file, user, password))
```

I am getting the following error:

> InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ='+'{};Uid={};Pwd={};'.format(db_file, user, password))
>
> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Try `'DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ='+ ...`

Comment: I tied that but no help!

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Office 365, the ODBC driver won't be accessible to external programs, so you need to install it separately

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you help me with how it needs to be done?

Comment: Well, start by providing the version of Access and Office 365 you're using, then I can link you the appropriate version of the database engine.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus